# Outline / Silhouette rendering with OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I know there are several techniques to achieve this, but none of them seems sufficient.

- Using a sobel / laplace filter doesn't find all the correct edges (and finds unwanted edges), is slow and doesn't give me control over the outline width.
- What i have settled on for now is rendering the backside of my objects first with a solid color and a little bigger than the actual objects. The result does look good, but i really want my outlines to have a constant width.
- I already tried rendering the backside of my objects with thick wireframe lines. Gives me a constant outline width, but line width is deprecated, produces rendering artifacts and leaves gaps, if the outline abruptly changes direction (like on a cube for example). I have not yet tried using a third rendering pass drawing a point the size of the wireframe lines for each vertex, because of the other problems with this technique.

Any ideas?

*edit* I even looked at finding the edges myself using a geometry shader, as described in http://prideout.net/blog/?p=54, but it suffers from the same gaps as the wireframe technique.

*edit* I was able to get rid of the rendering artifacts with the wireframe technique by disabling the `GL_DEPTH_TEST` while drawing the outlines. Unfortunately i also lost the outlines on overlapping objects...

My goal is to get the same effect they use on characters in the Dragons Lair 3 game. Does anyone know how they did it?

Comment: what are you exactly after? I have not seen DS3 so I dont know.. do you want real edge detection (with edges also inside the rendered object) or are you just looking for the outer silhouette of an object? I assume you're talking about a 3d object.. but maybe im wrong and you are working with a 2D image and you just want to do 2D postprocessing

Comment: Im trying to get the outlining often used with cel / toon shading to achieve a cartoony look. So i don't want a complete wireframe model (which would be easy), but i don't only want the outer silhouette either. Try googeling "cel shading" or "toon shading". You can also easily get some picture of Dragons Lair 3 by using Google picture search ;)

Comment: yes I thought so, see my answer you get much better results than writing a simple common toon shader (you dont get all thet artifacts when the normals are almost perpendicular to the viewer)

Comment: I assume by "Dragons Lair 3", you mean the realtime-rendered "Dragon's Lair 3D", and not Dragon's Lair III (which was all hand-animated FMV, like the original Dragon's Lair and Dragon's Lair II).  It looked to me like Dragon's Lair 3D was actually drawing single-pixel-wide wireframe lines. along character silhouettes and along certain pre-specified triangle edges (flap of the backpack, etc.  Didn't look like they were doing anything particularly fancy, but it worked really well for their flat-shaded cartoon look.

Comment: Yes, i think you are right about the name :) Sounds fancy enough - using the backface culling method i tried the single-pixel-wide lines wouldn't be visible with depth buffering. Without depth buffering you could see the wireframe of the backside of an object. So they'd have to compute which lines to draw somehow. Did they have geometry shaders in 2002?

Answer (score 3):

in case you're after real edge detection, Ive found that you can get pretty good results with a convolution LoG (Laplacian over Gaussian) 5x5 kernel, applied to the depth buffer and blended over the rendered object (possibly with a decent FSAA). You need some tuning in the fragment shader in order to clamp the blended outline, but the results are good. (and its a matter of what you really want, btw)

note that:

1) Laplace filtering and log filtering are different things and produce different results

2) if you apply the convolution **on the depth buffer**, instead of the rendered image, you end up with totally different results, firthermore, if an outline width conrol is desired, a dilate filter followed by a selective-erode pass can be applied, this way you will end up with a render that closely match a hand drawn sketch made with a marker, and you have fine control over tip size but at the cost of 2 extra pass

Comment: Dude, what's up with the angry note to moderators. They're all volunteers, be nice to them.

Comment: -1: for the CAPS LOCK note to moderators. Rather than just reposting the same answer **three times**, why don't you *change* your post so that it explains in detail what the technique is and how it differs from what the OP said that he'd tried?

Comment: Also, I don't see how your method gives him the explicit control over the outline width that he seems to want.

Comment: I dont have to change a perfectly valid answer just because the moderator does not undertsand it. The user is not really complaining about outline width but about edge detection correctness, and this way you will get edges way more correct than applying a sobel/lplacian on a render. As a note, if an explicit control is desired over the detected outline, a dilate filter can be applied, followed by a selectively erode filter (I did it few weeks ago). you end up with a render that closely match a hand-drawn sketch made with a marker, and you have fine control over tip size

Comment: Answering rudeness in kind only leads to further rudeness. Also, unless the moderators talked to you outside of comments (moderators are the ones with diamonds at the end of their names), I have yet to see any "personal sarcasm" from them.

Comment: you're right, I was wrong, the sarcasm didnt came from the moderator but from you, and I dont see how adding a personal offence like fail, looser or whatever it was helps other understand. On my part, I corrected the caps and note. retain from using that kind of comments if you dont want to hurt others feeling

Comment: The dilate filter is an interesting idea, but it sounds very inefficient. Perhaps i should have clarified this, we are talking real time rendering here.

Comment: I implemented a simple dilate/erode 2 pass rendering on a laptop with a 330M and did not get any difference in fps loss, I found I really underestimated postprocessing power, even on older hardware. Maybe you could give it a try

Comment: also note that a 5x5 kernel will generally produce a more marked outline (and perform a better edge detection), and on todays hardware the fps loss from a 3x3 kernel is almost negligible

Comment: @user815129 Don't worry about old you-know-who, he really needs to work on his people skills; very quick to criticise others. That sort of attitude is in fact strongly discouraged here because it drives new users away from the SE sites. I experienced this first hand on a number of occasions and have since asked him to cease answering any questions that I post.